# Calculus - Finding the Cubic Function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

A cubic has a minimum at $x=−1$ and a maximum at $x=3$. The cubic passes through the point $(1,4)$, where it has a gradient of $6$. Find the equation of the cubic.

The answers have as one of their steps:

$$f'(x)= \frac{-6(x+1)(x-3) }4$$

And I do not understand how they got this from the information given. Can someone please explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: You have $f'(x)$. Compute $f(x) = \int f'(x) dx$ and figure out what the constant term must be.

Comment: Try assuming a general cubic of the form $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$and fitting the info to it.

Comment: You can sub in $(1,4)$ in to the general cubic. Now find the derivative and examine the stationary points.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a cubic then $f'$ is a quadratic. Since $f$ has a minimum at $-1$ and a maximum at $4$, it follows that $f'(-1)=f'(4)=0$ and $f'$ should be positive in $(-1,4)$. So $f'$ has the form 
$$f'(x)=a(x+1)(x-4)$$
with $a<0$. Now by letting $f'(1)=6$, we are able to find $a=6/((1+1)(1-3))=-6/4$, and we obtain
$$f'(x)= \frac{-6(x+1)(x-4)}4.$$
Finally
$$f(x)=f(1)+\int_1^x f'(t) dt=4+\int_1^x f'(t) dt.$$